# HyperLink Sublime Package to open included PHP file

Tags: php, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, package

I found this package useful to Quickly and easily jump between your files.
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HyperClick

But this package is only restricted to JS, Stylus and SASS files. Is there a package where I can have this feature to quickly switch between files in PHP Format too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is [goto-documentation](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-2-goto-documentation). This supports PHP as well

**Update**:

> It's not the documentation I need [...] If I click on xyz.php it has to open the file xyz.php in code editor

This use case is solved by [Open-Include](https://github.com/titoBouzout/Open-Include)

To install on OSX:

```
cd ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages
git clone https://github.com/titoBouzout/Open-Include.git
```

And restart sublime. After that when you have `include "xyz.php"` you place your cursor within the string and hit `cmd-D` and it will open xyz.php.

Personally I use `cmd-T` and start typing the name for switching within files in the project

Comment: Hey Hansaplast,  


It's not the documentation I need..   

For example, there's a line in php file like below,  

`  
require_once '/includes/plugins/xyz.php';  
`   
If I click on xyz.php it has to open the file xyz.php in code editor.  
  

Check the HyperClick package for JS here:   https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HyperClick

Comment: @vgnanendra I see, I added another sublime package to the answer

Comment: awesome.. that was helpful. Thank you @Hansaplast :)

Comment: Is Open-include for sublimetext 2 ? if no what can i use for the same.

Comment: @nepsdotin I have no idea, I am on sublime 3. Did you try to install it?